# pandas group by and count category

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
Date            User    Tradetype  Cost
2022-01-01      User1    Sell       $1
2022-01-01      User1    Buy        $2
2022-01-01      User1    Sell       $0
2022-01-01      User2    Buy        $1
2022-01-01     User2     Sell       $1
```

I am looking to aggregate it in such a way that I get the following output

```
User      Date         Tradetype      Count    TotalCost
User1    2022-01-01     Buy             2       $2
User1    2022-01-01     Sell            2       $2
User2    2022-01-01     Buy             1       $1
User2    2022-01-01     Sell            1       $1
```

I have tried a `df.groupby('User')` but not sure how to proceed further, as the `Tradetype` has to be aggregated as well.
Any inputs on how I can achieve this in `pandas`?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you check your input dataframe?  How do you get a count of two for User1 Buy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01"],
        "User": ["User1", "User1", "User1", "User2", "User2"],
        "Tradetype": ["Sell", "Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell"],
        "Cost": ["$1", "$2", "$0", "$1", "$1"],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it with Pandas [pipe](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) and [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), and Python's [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```py
df = (
    df.groupby(["User", "Date", "Tradetype"])
    .agg(list)
    .pipe(
        lambda df_: df_.assign(
            Count=df_["Cost"].apply(len),
            TotalCost=df_["Cost"].apply(
                lambda x: f"${sum([int(c.strip('$')) for c in x])}"
            ),
        )
    )
    .drop(columns="Cost")
    .reset_index()
)
```

Then:

```py
print(df)
# Output

    User        Date Tradetype  Count TotalCost
0  User1  2022-01-01       Buy      1        $2
1  User1  2022-01-01      Sell      2        $1
2  User2  2022-01-01       Buy      1        $1
3  User2  2022-01-01      Sell      1        $1
```

Answer (score 1):

(
df.groupby(['Date','User','Tradetype'])

['Cost'].agg(['count','sum']).reset_index()

)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
df['Cost'] = df.Cost.str.lstrip('$').astype(int)
pd.merge(
    df.rename(columns={'Cost':'TotalCost'}).groupby(by=['Date', 'User', 'Tradetype']).sum(),
    df.rename(columns={'Cost':'Count'}).groupby(by=['Date', 'User', 'Tradetype']).count(),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
).reset_index()
```

Result:

```
         Date   User Tradetype  TotalCost  Count
0  2022-01-01  User1       Buy          2      1
1  2022-01-01  User1      Sell          1      2
2  2022-01-01  User2       Buy          1      1
3  2022-01-01  User2      Sell          1      1
```

Answer (score 0):

df.groupby(［'User'，'Tradetype'］).agg(['sum','count'])

you can group both user and tradetype columns and apply count and sum functions